# Extend Romex without a box to run to other side of stud

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'm replacing a bathroom vanity light fixture. I removed the old, off-centered fixture, which was placed on top of a stud (not sure if it was to code-- the wiring was in a rectangular box on the right side of the stud, with the fixture bracket nailed directly to the stud).

The (centered) new fixture needs to be on the left side of the stud. I have figured out how to do this by attaching a shim to the left side of the stud and a fan box to the shim for the fixture wiring. I asked a previous question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/256140/mount-vanity-light-fixture-box-overlapping-stud-with-more-wiring-volume-than-pan) that helped with this.

However, the existing Romex is too short to comfortably be threaded through a hole in the stud/shim and into the fan box on the other side. I was going to leave the old box in place, using it as a pure junction box (no fixture/switch/outlet) and running a short length of Romex from this box, through the stud/shim, to the fan box on the other side. However, I've learned it is a bad idea/against code to enclose a junction box in the wall, and I don't want a junction box cover sitting right behind my vanity light.

So, what I need to do is add maybe 6 inches to the existing Romex, without a box, so that it can be run directly into the new box on the other side of the stud. I have seen some [no-box splice kit products](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-A22899-000/202204326), but it's unclear to me when these are allowed by code. Can I use one of these kits in my situation, or is there a better alternative approach?

[image]

**UPDATE**: I ended up moving the light fixture up a few inches so that I could get the necessary slack to route it through the stud to the other side. Here is a picture of my solution-- is there anything about this arrangement that looks off/unsafe?

[image]

Comment: make a trench for the cable, then cover it with metal plate

Comment: Those splice kits are only approved for repairs.

Comment: Do you have any slack in your romex cable outside of the box?  If you're lucky you might just have a crimp on the box which is preventing you from getting more length.  You could then remove the box and run the wire through the stud to a new box on the other side.
<br>
Tailing on @ecnerwal's idea - if you can follow the wire to a less unsightly place you could move the junction box.
<br>
Otherwise I'd just call an electrician - it should be fairly easy for them to run a new cable and you'll get the peace of mind that everything is done correctly.

Comment: I didn't have slack, but I ended up moving the light fixture up a few inches to get the necessary slack to run it through the stud-- updated pic above, see any issue there?

Answer (score 3):

The "better approach" is to replace the whole cable back to the next junction box or switch box; or to a point where you can stand to have a junction box cover plate.

Certain in-wall splice kits may be allowed - depends on your LAHJ and applicable code. When code is adopted, the LAHJ can choose to strike or amend certain things in the national model codes before adopting them, so that's got to be checked on the local level.